# Screen orientation not changing despite calls to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I would like to add the functionality to change the screen orientation for various views in my app. Having read various tutorials, I implemented the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in each of my view controllers, and got each of them to return yes, as well as log the call to the console, like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    NSLog(@"shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation called");
    return YES;
}
```

When I run this on the simulator and change the orientation, I get the log message but nothing on the screen changes. I've tried to find how this could happen but everywhere I've looked says problems are associated with the method not being called, even though it is in my case. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure every single on-screen view controller is returning `YES` from this? Even a single view controller that doesn't support rotation can prevent the whole thing from rotating.

Comment: have you tried restarting Xcode? it happened to me once and it did the trick. if not you could make a category in the app delegate to override the should auto rotate method. if restarting and clearing doesn't work tell me and i'll show you how to override it in the app delegate.

Comment: Could you tell me about viewcontroller structure?
you're view is singleViewcontroller? or sth viewController inner other viewController?

Comment: If you are seeing the NSLog, then also try outputting the orientation you are receiving and make sure its actually different.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've looked at the value of interfaceOrientation in each of these log outputs and they seem to be correct, however nothing is happening to the interface. I've implemented this method and got it to return YES in every UIViewController subclass in the project, just to be sure. Also, the method appears to be called (judging by the log output) every time I change the orientation EXCEPT when going to portrait (not upside down), which is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to know that in your code are you using every views by code or .xib.

Also you need to set autorisizing property for every component...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: there was a direct UIViewController object being initialised in the code, and changing it to my own simple base class solved the issue. Thanks for the advice!